# How to create random SQLqueries based on database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, random

For testing purposes I require a large amount of queries. 
Creating this manually is not an option, so I am searching a tool which will do this automatically.

Sadly, the only solution I found (sqlsmith), is limited to postgres and SQLite. 
Are there any similar tools for SQL-Server?

Comment: Generating random queries is useful to test the database's implementation of its parser (which is the purpose of sqlsmith). Is that your intended purpose? If not, what do you think a random query generator will do for you?

Comment: Basically, I just need the queries to work with the Tuning Advisor. Creating all of these manually would be very time-consuming.

Comment: Generating random queries to feed to the tuning advisor would be completely pointless, because you're creating a load that does not reflect actual usage (and you'll get nonsensical advice as a result). If you lack the insight to create indexes before you know your load, you're better off waiting for actual applications and tuning based on profiler traces of those. To further drive the point home: you'd be better off getting something that will create *random indexes* for you, and skip the middleman with the random queries...

Comment: Are you hoping to find a tool that will just generate random queries against your database so you can run them through the tuning advisor? What purpose does this serve???

Comment: To be honest, I never worked with the Tuning Advisor before. I just have the requirement in my assignment to use a minimum of 10'000 queries. (Which I am sure aren't meant to be created manually, nor be taken from actual usage since its a purely experimental database)

Comment: What you're sure about and what the actual intent of the assignment is may be different things. I'd go back to whoever gave you the assignment and ask them where the 10,000 queries are supposed to come from, and specifically, if they are not to be taken from live load, why they would be meaningful input to Tuning Advisor (and hence, what the assignment is supposed to accomplish). Never do things that appear to make no sense without at least a token effort to validate that they really want you to do the things that make no sense (there's still plenty of time to do them afterwards).

Comment: Note specifically that if you are able to produce 10,000 queries that *are* a meaningful representation of the load, from scratch, then you are likely also clever enough to immediately come up with the indexes to serve them, and you'd have no need of Tuning Advisor. That's another reason why this makes little sense, except as an exercise of how to run Tuning Advisor, which is not a very complicated skill (and could be done just as well with 10 queries as it could be with 10,000).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I do not know from what random place people will want to travel to a random other place, so instead, let's create roads for every possible combination of origin and destination".

That sounds kind of insane, doesn't it? The same applies to what you seem to be wanting to achieve. You basically are hoping to find a tool that generates random queries against your database so you can feed them to the tuning advisor, which will then suggest query optimization indexes for hypothetical queries.

If you want to performance tune your database, you should have a pretty good idea of the type of questions your users will be throwing at it, as well as the structure of your data. Typical questions that will help you get started would be things like:

- What is the most common search my users would do against this table?
- What criteria are they most likely to use?
- Which columns are guaranteed or likely to contain unique data in every row?
- Which columns will most likely have a low selectivity of data? (I.e. Male/Female)

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for generate random data for multiple tables ? we generally use redgate data genearator tool for the same.

for SQL tuning purpose I would suggest

https://www.brentozar.com/blitzindex/

http://www.nguyenlamminhdieu.com/zone/213/news/vi-VN/zone/213/news/351-database-engine-tuning-advisor-in-sql-server.aspx